# Emacs transliteration?

Tags: emacs, transliteration

Is there some way to get transliteration to work in Emacs, sort of like it does in Gmail now? I am particularly interested in getting it to work in Cyrillic.

For reference, Gmail does something like the following:
I can type `svoboda` and it will output `свобода`. This allows somebody like me who speaks Russian but cannot type to easily input Cyrillic characters. In Gmail this works with other languages, but I am only really worried about Cyrillic.

Comment: Your question would reach a wider audience if you explained what kind of transliteration Gmail provides that you like. If you're trying to remap your keyboard, look under “Input methods” in the Emacs manual.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the question to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this will do it:

<kbd>M-x set-input-method cyrillic-translit</kbd>

Comment: Ooh, exactly what I was looking for. I didn't think it would be included by default--Emacs never ceases to surprise me.

Comment: Oh yeah, some more useful info: ucs seems to be the standard US keyboard, for reverting it, and the `set-input-method` command can also be accessed via C-x RET C-\.

Comment: If you wish to transliterate back to latin characters, you can use the command `standard-display-cyrillic-translit`.

Comment: Regarding my (old) comment about `ucs`--it isn't actually the standard us keyboard; it allows you to type arbitrary unicode characters by entering uXXXX where XXXX is the hexidecimal number of the character.